# How to sort ActiveRecord results by associated model count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

```
class Cafe < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This is cafe.rb model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cafe
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and this is postq.rb. post is like replies.

I want to create new cafe array and sort it by cafe.posts.count.
Finally, I will show top two cafes that have many replies.

I've tried some sorting codes like,

```
@cafe_by_posts = Cafe.joins(:post).order('posts.size dsc')
```

but it didn't work. The error said that cafe has no association with post.
how can I sort ruby array by associated model count?

I'm not good at english, I'll appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey in `mysql` you can directly used like

```
@cafe_by_posts = Cafe.joins(:posts).group("posts.cafe_id").order('count(posts.cafe_id) desc')
```

You can directly select Top 2 using `limit`

```
 @cafe_by_posts = Cafe.joins(:posts).group("posts.cafe_id").order('count(posts.cafe_id) desc').limit(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Relation name is `posts` not `post`, look:

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Ordering should be done by SQL constraint. 
There is no `dsc` sort order in MySQL, it is `desc`. So, here you go:

```
 @cafe_by_posts = Cafe.joins(:posts)
                      .group('posts.cafe_id')
                      .order('COUNT(posts.cafe_id) DESC')
                      .limit(2) # to retrieve only 2 topmost records
```

Comment: if group `posts.id` then it only return one record because `posts.id` is uniq, n `group_by` is used on hash giving error of arguments only use `group`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [counter_cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :cafe, counter_cache: true
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Then add a migration:

```
add_column :cafe, :posts_count, :integer, default: 0
```

then you can query as

```
@cafe_by_posts = Cafe.order('posts_count DESC')
```